# How can I make my room darker at night?

Tags: windows, recessed-lighting, blinds

I live in a place where we do not have completely dark nights in the summer.

This is how my room looks like (picture from the web, just example - Sliding doors with vertical blinds).

[image]

I'm looking for an easy solution. And I do know that sleeping masks exist, I just hate them.

Possible solutions in my understanding:

1. Tint attached directly to windows -  then I do not have control during the day.
2. Couple of blankets pinned in front of the blinds - looks ugly.
3. Get new curtains - hard to install (expensive?)

Comment: Turn off the lights....   sorry, could not resist

Comment: Ok......  black out shades.

Comment: @shirlockhomes, OMG. I didn't know you can black out shades. Can you please post this as an answer so I can accept that? It really helps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a bedroom with lots of windows darker?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/4609/how-can-i-make-a-bedroom-with-lots-of-windows-darker)

Answer (score 1):

Look for some black out shades.  They come in several styles and colors. The fit is important so measure carefully.  Once they are closed, little to no outside light comes through.  Good luck   http://www.levolor.com/products/blinds/customsizenow/cellular-shades/

Comment: They are a GREAT idea! Definitely looking into them when we buy our next house